# Adjust matplotlib plot sizes

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to spy a numpy matrix but its hardly useful because the x axis is very compressed and I cant see anything in the plot.

[image]

How can I make the x axis bigger so I can actually see something useful?

This is the code I am using to produce this result. The size of C is 1500x76

```
    plt.spy(world.C)
    plt.show(
```

Answer (score 0):

[`spy`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.spy.html) has an `aspect` parameter for this purpose:

```
plt.spy(world.C, aspect='auto')
```